# How do I copy/paste an icon into a launcher in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome, icons

In MacOSX I can copy an icon from any document/folder/application by doing Cmd-i on the object and then copying (i.e. Cmd-c) the icon and pasting the icon on another object (by bringing up the information via Cmd-i and pasting the icon saved to the clipboard over the original icon).

Is there a way to do this in Ubuntu? I am running 10.04. Gnome 2.30.2

Answer (score 0):

You can press *Ctrl+i* (it opens the Properties window for the file/directory) and then just drag 'n drop another icon from somewhere else on the top of it. That works at least if the icon you are dragging and dropping is a custom image and not some kind of system icon.

You may also open up the Properties window, click on the icon in that one and then choose another icon. If you don't know where to find the icons, press *Ctrl+l* and type */usr/share/icons* as the location.

Well, give it a spin!

Comment: I'm trying to change the icon of a launcher I created. I do Ctrl+i but I can't drag on drop anything on it. 

I'm trying to drag and drop a .exe file from a Windows application. Wine seems to be able to detect the icon since it uses the original Windows icon as an emblem in conjunction with the Wine file icon. 

Any other tips? How does Gnome map icons to files?